# Getting Out of memory: Java heap space. OR GC overhead limit exceeded when building release APK after Android studio 3.4 update

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

After upgrade of Android Studio 3.4 getting below error.
Gradel plugin version is: `3.4.0`

> Out of memory: Java heap space. Please assign more memory to Gradle in
>   the project's gradle.properties file. For example, the following line,
>   in the gradle.properties file sets the maximum Java heap size to
>
> 1,024 MB: *org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m* Read Gradle's
>
> configuration guide Read about Java's heap size

OR

> GC overhead limit exceeded

I have applied below solution but it doesn't work.

**Option: 1**

```
dexOptions {
   javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

**Option: 2**

```
org.gradle.configureondemand=false
```

**Option: 3**

Open gradle.properties file from your project tree add this line at the memory allocation line

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX\:MaxHeapSize\=256m -Xmx256m
```

or

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX\:MaxHeapSize\=512m -Xmx512m
```

or

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX\:MaxHeapSize\=1024m -Xmx1024m
```

Please help me to solve this issue. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: issue registered at https://issuetracker.google.com/u/0/issues/131858815

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know it is a valid answer or not.

**I have downgraded my gradle plugin version `3.4.0` to `3.3.2`**

It's work perfectly.

Comment: nope, it's not correct :D

Answer (score 2):

1024M is not much for Gradle, for example:

```
# @see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx5084M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
```

try values alike `-Xmx2048M` or `-Xmx4096M` ...

Comment: I have tried with all option(-Xmx1024M, -Xmx2048M, -Xmx3072M,-Xmx4096M,--Xmx5084M) but it doesn't work.

Comment: This may depend how much physical RAM the OS has to offer.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**, It is working for me.

Replace below code to your `gradle.properties` file

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.
# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.
# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html
# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m
# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : Start Android studio and close any open project (File > Close Project).

Step 2 : On Welcome window, Go to Configure > Settings.

Step 3 : Go to Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler

Step 4 : Change Build process heap size (Mbytes) to 512 and Additional build process to VM Options to -Xmx512m. Or any memory allocation in correspondent to your PC

Step 5 : Revalidate/Restart Android Studio.